# Convergence of sum of power series and numerical series.

Tags: power-series

Considering the following series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^n}(x+2)^n + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^3}{\sqrt {n!}}$$

We need to calculate the domain of convergence of this series.

Well the first series is a power series, it's easy to calculate the radius of convergence (it's 2). So the domain of convergence is $-4<x<0$

For the second series we need to see if the series in convergent or divergent, right? (Since it's a numerical series). Well I concluded it's divergent...

Now in $-4<x<0$ the series is divergent because it's the sum of a divergent series and a convergent series, right? But what happens outside the domain of convergence of the first series? Well, since we have two divergent series we can't conclude anything right? Then how should I proceed?. Thanks!

Comment: The second series is convergent since for big enough $n$ we have $n! > n^{10}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for the second series, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$, where $a_n=\frac{n^3}{\sqrt{n!}}$, the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#The_test) asserts

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{(n+1)^3}{n^3}\frac{\sqrt{n!}}{\sqrt{(n+1)!}}\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\left(1+\frac1n\right)^3\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Therefore, the series converges.

The sum of the two series converge for $-4<x<0$